# Issue with installing Facebook CTF

Tags: facebook, ctf

I am trying to install Facebook CTF from https://github.com/facebook/fbctf

Following the instructions, I execute ./extra/provision.sh -m prod -s $PWD

All goes well, until it gets to the section where it runs grunt. It's hitting this code in a javascript file

```
const proto = Object.defineProperties(() => {}, {
        ...styles,
        level: {
                enumerable: true,
                get() {
                        return this._generator.level;
                },
                set(level) {
                        this._generator.level = level;
                }
        }
});
```

It's balking at the ellipsis in front of styles.

It's giving this error.

```
        ...styles,
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

Has anyone run into this error when install fbctf or can spot a Javascript error? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Quick Setup instructions and ran into a similar issue.
I resolved by it upgrading my nodejs version using npm in the instructions below.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version

Note: I did the nodejs installation on command line before running the install command.